# How to replace dashes with underscores within the square brackets using regex Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace dashes within the square brackets with underscores but it replaces all dashes with underscores in string.

For example, I want to replace

```
"[a]-[a-gamma]"
```

with

```
"[a]-[a_gamma]"
```

but it replaces *all* dashes from the string with underscores.

Comment: where is your regex? Also, is is guranteed that `-` in brackets is preceded by alphabet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
String n="[a]-[a-gamma]";
System.out.println(n.replaceAll("-(?=[^\\[\\]]*\\])", "_"));
```

As for the regex itself, I match the `-` symbol only if it is followed by non-`[`s and non-`]`s until the engine finds the `]`. Then, we are "inside" the `[]`s. There can be a situation when this is not quite true (4th hyphen in `[a-z]-[a-z] - ] [a-z]`), but I hope it is not your case.

[IDEONE Demo](https://ideone.com/leB7Su)

Output:

```
[a]-[a_gamma]
```

Comment: I prefer to provide solutions tested in the specific language environment, thus usually a bit later than the rest. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
str = str.replaceAll("-(?![^\\]]*\\[)", "_");
```

The regex matches dashes whose next square bracket character is *not* an opening square bracket.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(?=[^\\[]*\\])
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bN8dL3/6

Answer (score 1):

If your brackets are balanced (or if an unclosed bracket is considered opened by default until the end), you can use this way that needs few steps to find a match:

pattern:

```
((?:\\G(?!\\A)|[^\\[]*\\[)[^\\]-]*)-
```

replacement:

```
$1_
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dM5qH4/1)

pattern details:

```
(                   # open the capture group 1
    (?:             # open a non capturing group for the 2 possible beginings
        \\G (?!\\A) # this one succeeds immediately after the last match
      |
        [^\\[]* \\[ # this one reach the first opening bracket
                    # (so it is the first match)
    )
    [^\\]-]*        # all that is not a closing bracket or a dash
)                   # close the capture group
-                   # the dash
```

The `\G` anchor marks the position after the last match. But at the begining (since there isn't already a match), it matches by default the start of the string. This is the reason why I added `(?!\A)` to fail at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
/\[[^\]]*?(-)[^\[]*?\]/g
```

Match group extracted:

```
"[a]-[a-gamma] - [[ - - [123-567567]]]"
       ^                    ^
```

Explanation available here: https://regex101.com/r/oC2xE0/1